# is this node.js mustache partials functionality ideal?

Tags: node.js, express, partial-views, mustache

I'm new to node and have been trying to find a way to integrate mustache in a way thats flexible for how I build templates.  After trying hogan, mustache-express and the other permutations of mustache, I found the following to make sense to me.

Im not sure if there is a more efficient way of handling this. Basically I like to have control of partial templates so I can load them in module positions on a master template. So this is the basic setup

I have 3 partial templates and one wrapper/master template, the following values are just for example.

**./views/wrapper.tpl**

```
<html>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<body>
    <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    <div>{{> position_1 }}</div>
    <div>{{> position_2 }}</div>
    <div>{{> position_3 }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**./views/module_1.tpl**

```
<h2>{{module_1.title}}</h2>
<p>{{module_1.body}}</p>
```

**./views/module_2.tpl**

```
<h2>{{module_2.title}}</h2>
<p>{{module_2.body}}</p>
```

**./views/module_3.tpl**

```
<h2>{{module_3.title}}</h2>
<p>{{module_3.body}}</p>
```

Im using Express but removed the default jade render engine. I only included the code that needs to be added to a default express install. 
mustache and fs are needed

```
.
.
.
var mustache = require('mustache');
var fs = require('fs');
.
.
.
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // grab master template
    var wrapper = fs.readFileSync('./views/wrapper.tpl', "utf8");

    // load data that will be used in template & partials
    var data = {
                'title': 'dashboard',
                'heading': 'welcome to your dashboard',
                'module_1':{
                            'title': 'module 1 title', 
                            'body': 'module 1 body'},
                'module_2':{
                            'title': 'module 2 title', 
                            'body': 'module 2 body'},
                'module_3':{
                            'title': 'module 3 title', 
                            'body': 'module 3 body'}};

    // load partial templates
    var partials = {'position_1': fs.readFileSync('./views/module_1.tpl', "utf8"),
                    'position_2': fs.readFileSync('./views/module_2.tpl', "utf8"),
                    'position_3': fs.readFileSync('./views/module_3.tpl', "utf8")}

    // include partials and then replace variables with given data
    var html = mustache.to_html(wrapper, data, partials);

    // send output to browser
    res.send(html);

});
.
.
.
.
```

This to me makes alot more sense then other examples I have seen, and it works well with mustache.  I am able to give the user custom control as to where they want the modules to be positioned. So my questions are

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Is there anything wrong with the way Im going about this?

By bypassing Express rendering capabilities what am I missing out?

Why should I use libraries like consolidate and add another layer to express?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want express rendering, thats fine in my book, I even removed the whole module in some of my lab projects just to get a better understanding of routing in node.
However I'd really advice against using readFileSync since It's a blocking method and will make concurency a problem, always use readFile so you get that async callback.